# Get most frequent option, each day, on a week range

Tags: sql, postgresql

I had another question, but it was kinda confusing so I'll try to make simple this time.

I got a table "option":

```
id  |  option_name
1   "Option 1"
2   "Option 2"
3   "Option 3"
4   "Option 4"
5   "Option 5"
6   "Option 6"
7   "Option 7"
```

and another table "user" with some user information. Then I created a table named "daily_voting" where each day, each user can choose an option. It should be like this:

```
user_id | option_id | timestamp
1  1  2018-12-24 00:01:00.091055-03
2  1  2018-12-24 01:01:00.091055-03
3  2  2018-12-24 02:01:00.091055-03
1  2  2018-12-25 00:01:00.091055-03
2  2  2018-12-25 00:02:00.091055-03
3  5  2018-12-26 00:02:00.091055-03
```

If I do:

```
select count(*) as votes, option_id, date_trunc('day', daily_voting.timestamp) as day
from daily_voting
where date_trunc('day', daily_voting.timestamp) = '2018-12-24 00:00:00-03'
group by option_id, day
order by votes desc
limit 1
```

I would get:

```
votes | option_id | day
2    1    2018-12-24 00:00:00-03
```

What I need is, passing a week range from current day, probably from:

```
date_trunc('week', current_date) and date_trunc('week', current_date+7)
```

A query where the output would be:

```
votes | option_id | day
2    1    2018-12-24 00:00:00-03
2    2    2018-12-25 00:00:00-03
1    5    2018-12-26 00:00:00-03
```

Comment: i think for second row no of votes will be 3 for option id 2 or date for one of the option id 2 is out of range from  24 to 30 date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ROW_NUMBER()` will give you a rank.

```
SELECT Votes, Option_ID, Day
FROM (
SELECT Votes, Option_id, day, row_number() over (partition by day order by votes DESC) AS VoteRank
FROM (
select count(*) as votes, option_id, date_trunc('day', daily_voting.timestamp) as day
from daily_voting
where date_trunc('day', daily_voting.timestamp) BETWEEN '2018-12-24' AND '2018-12-31'
group by option_id, day
)Aux ) T
WHERE VoteRank = 1
```

You're free to define the date range using a different method of course.